# An empty super class for the sake of a common ancestor

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I got a C# class which is making some actions based on data it receives which is held in other classes:

```
public Class ActionClass
{
    public void DoStuff(List<MyItemsClass> data) { ... }
}
```

It started as a single class with a single items class, but then I needed to add another action class which does its stuff in a different way and receives different items.

Now I got an abstract class for the action part which enforces its derived class to implement how they do their stuff. It left me with a dilemma about the items class.. I want to have a single signature in the abstract class which receives the needed items class:

```
public abstract DoStuff(List<MySuperItemsClass> data);
```

So I created a common ancestor also to the 2 different items classes. However, since they have nothing in common, I got an empty class which now serves only for the purpose of being able to pass that super class, while dynamically instantiating the correct derived classes.

Is it a good practice to have an empty class for the purpose of creating a type? Is there another more common way of achieving what I need without the use of an empty class?

Comment: On the face of it, this seems like a case for generics? Otherwise you already have a built in empty class for deriving things with nothing in common - `object`

Comment: This is what interfaces are for.

Comment: Is there any actual common code? If not, it may be that you're trying to force a coding pattern that isn't actually applicable to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use generic interface instead of abstract class. Class can implement multiple interfaces.

```
interface IActionClass<T>
{
    void DoStuff(T data);
}

class MyClass : IActionClass<List<MySuperItemsClass>>, IActionClass<int>
{
    public void DoStuff(List<MySuperItemsClass> data) { }

    public void DoStuff(int data) { }
}
```